# how to write a program to display beep in a system using c++

Tags: c++, c

Im new to C++ , I need code to run and execute a beep program using LCD printf functions

how to write a program to display beep in a system using c++

Comment: Probably your question is a bit confusing as to understand what do you mean by DISPLAYING A BEEP..If you mean to make a BEEP sound then you may find answers below and if you mean something else then do update your question!!! :)

Comment: Does your LCD contain a speaker?  In all of my embedded projects, not one LCD had a speaker attached to it.  Although with embedded systems, your LCD could be different.  Do you need to flash the LCD instead of making an audible tone?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:0

```
cout << '\a';
```

or try this:-

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    Beep(200,1000);      
    cin.get(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Also check out the [Beep function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
   std::cout << '\a';

   OR

   printf("\a");
```